# Issue implementing C library (libircclient) into a iOS project (i386/armv7/x64)

Tags: ios, cocoa, gcc

I'm trying to build a iOS app with support for IRC chat. I've found the following library which seems very ease to implement and also has a example how to do this in Cocoa:

Libircclient on sourceforge (v1.0)
IRCClient on GitHub by Jonasschnelli (v1.3)

(sorry i can't add more than 2 hyperlinks)

However I keep getting these errors in my project:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IRCClientSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

I followed this answer for the implementation:

[iPhone - Why can the compiler not find some includes when building for ARM architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878292/iphone-why-can-the-compiler-not-find-some-includes-when-building-for-arm-archi)

Created a Cocoa static library project which actually builds for iOS6 like it describes. But when I'm trying to use the Cocoa example files in combination with the cocoa static library in  a simple 1 view iOS project the error pops up. So in my project i have the following files:

As described in the question

```
- libircclient.c 
- included the ../include folder as header search which contains the .h files.
```

From the cocoa example, but remove the include to cocoa.h

```
- IRCClientSessionDelegate.h 
- IRCClientSession.h
- IRCClientChannelDelegate.h
- IRCClientChannel.h
```

ViewController.m where I add the following lines (without these lines it builds with no errors):

```
#import "IRCClientSession.h"
IRCClientSession *  session = [[IRCClientSession alloc] init];
```

Then I tried the second and third answers: Adjust the makefile for armv7 and i386 (-arch armv7), but same i386 error appears.

I'm not that good on these commands and not sure what the errors actually say. As I understand I have to build the C files against the iOS SDK and not against my MAC 64bit SDK. Thought I did that with the xcode static library but after actually using it, it gave me i386 errors. i386 is for simulator I guess. But building to a device results in the same i386 errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

[edit: removed the make errors since i was doing a make on the example folder, make in src folder works]

Comment: Your app is named "spammer" and it's trying to connect to IRC servers? I don't think I want to help you...

Comment: Thats just a .c file from the C library: https://github.com/jonasschnelli/IRCClient/blob/master/examples/spammer.c

Comment: Hmm I better skip the example folder when trying to build. Thats seems to be working better but I've still the same i386 error in my iOS project.