# Clang Cross Compiling for ARM?

Tags: c, linux, arm, clang, cross-compiling

Is it possible to set up Clang for cross compiling for the ARM processor? The host will likely be on x86 ( AMD64 - Probably Ubuntu 12.04 ) and the target would be ARM ( Raspberry Pi as well as Pandaboard - will do separate compilations for each ), I may at some point also wish to cross compile for the PowerPC architecture? The program source is in C.

Comment: Maybe this helps [Is cross-compiling for ARM on x86 with llvm/Clang possible?](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-June/050820.html)

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi I have examples that use clang in this repo and others.  3.2 allows for compiling straight to object rather than taking a step through assembly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878292/iphone-why-can-the-compiler-not-find-some-includes-when-building-for-arm-archi/17537169#17537169

Answer (score 31):

To cross-compile for Raspberry Pi running soft-float Linux distros add flags `-ccc-host-triple arm-eabi -marm -mfpu=vfp -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfloat-abi=softfp`

To cross-compile for Raspberry Pi running hard-float Linux distros use the flags `-ccc-host-triple arm-eabi -marm -mfpu=vfp -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfloat-abi=hard`

To cross-compile for Pandaboard use flags `-ccc-host-triple arm-eabiv7 -mthumb -mfpu=neon-fp16 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=hard` (assuming that your Pandaboard runs Ubuntu)

Note: more recent `clang` version use `-target` option instead of `-ccc-host-triple`

Comment: What flags for Raspbian, please?

Comment: Using clang-8: it is important to note that the documentation is incorrect: `-target <triple>` is not a recognised argument (though specified in the documentation), but `--target=<triple>` is.

Answer (score 2):

See [EmbToolkit](http://www.embtoolkit.org) project. It gives ability to generate clang/llvm
or gcc based cross compiler toolchain.