# Clang cross-compilation for ARM

Tags: c, arm, clang, llvm

I'm trying to compile a file containing `stdint.h` for ARM (specifically Cortex-M3) using `arm-none-eabi` (which is a Debian's package) headers. The command is:

```
clang -I/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/include \
    -target arm-none-eabi cfile.c -o cfile.o
```

(`-mcpu`, `-mfpu`, `-mfloat-abi` are left out for simplicity)

Returns an error:

```
In file included from cfile.c:1:
In file included from ./cfile.h:4:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/include/stdint.h:9:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib/clang/3.5.0/include/stdint.h:61:
In file included from /usr/include/stdint.h:25:
/usr/include/features.h:374:12: fatal error: 'sys/cdefs.h' file not found
#  include <sys/cdefs.h>
           ^
1 error generated.
```

I've been generally following [this guide](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html).

My versions:

```
$ clang --version
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (4.8.4-1+11-1) 4.8.4 20141219 (release)
```

Any ideas on how to approach solving this?

P.S.: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697614/clang-cross-compiling-for-arm).

Comment: What is your host system  (OSX) ? you may try to install g++-multilib

Comment: @Arseniy It's Debian x86_64.

Comment: Try to install   `g++-multilib` By the way, it's better to use `--sysroot` option. `--sysroot=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/`

Comment: Thanks, installing `g++-multilib` has solved the problem. Could you explain why that worked? Also, isn't `sysroot` supposed to be used with cross-compilers installed from zips (not as system's packages)?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue you have to install `g++-multilib`
`g++-multilib`  - the GNU C++ compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C++.
It will install required headers.

As an answer for `sysroot` option (from comments section):
You are absolutely right
`sysroot` supposed to be used with cross-compilers installed from zips. It was not clear from a question which compiler you are trying to use.

Comment: Do you know why GNU C++ compiler's headers worked with clang but GCC's didn't? And how exactly did that help since I'm still pointing to GCC's folder for resolving headers?

Comment: @andreyg It has helped because you installed these headers on your system. As you may see in your question , in compilation process were used system's header stdind.h from gcc look for stdint on system.